# SSL_* vs BIO_* functions

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I am new to openSSL and want to know about the difference in using SSL_* and BIO_* functions for reading and writing data. Also it would be great if we could have some examples telling the usecases for both.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

`SSL_*` functions operate on an SSL connection. `BIO_*` functions stand for basic `input and output` which are used for reading and writing operations over different input/output devices such as file, memory buffer or even socket connection.

`SSL_*` function performs the required encryption/decryption of the data whereas `BIO_*` does not.

There are plenty of use cases for both.

For `SSL_*` whenever you want to make an SSL client or server, you need this.

For reading and writing from the file or memory buffer, you may need `BIO_*` function. Common use is some `i2d_` or `d2i_` functions which writes or reads to/from an input/output device. For example, you want to write your public key to a `BIO_*` which can be memory buffer or a file, you can open the input into `BIO *` structure. Your writing code will not make any distinction about file or buffer and will write over `BIO *`